# Create a fabric network of networks

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

> How can we connect a single Fabric - node/peer to different Fabric
>   networks?

A company called **ABC** is part of 2 networks and hosting 2 different nodes. 
Can we create a **network of networks** where a single node can be part of many networks?

Answer (score 0):

First of All,

> In hyperledger fabric, we called network as a consortium

- The consortium has a group of organizations, each organization can have (n) of orderers and peers
- Coming to your question, yes peer can be part of multiple consortium as long as peer-organization is a member of that consortium